# AngularJS 2 setup in Eclipse with TypEsc plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eclipse, typescript

I am trying to setup a web project in Eclipse using AngularJS 2 and using the typescript plugin TypEsc (http://typecsdev.com/).

I have managed to get TypEsc working to the point where it compiling the .ts file into .js files.

When I try the simple Hello World example below I get the following errors.

```
*Multiple markers at this line
- Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.
- Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.*
```

What am I missing in my setup?

---

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
  <app></app>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2-polyfills.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/Rx.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2-all.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.html'
})

class App {
  target:string;
  constructor() {
    this.target = 'world';
  }
}

bootstrap(App);
```

Comment: You can follow the steps provided here in [angular quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at it. But what I am really looking for is to setup a project without using the NPM route. I would like to setup and build the project from Eclipse, if possible.

Comment: I suggest you that you try https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started